# How to send file to Sharepoint from Linux creating non existend directories

Tags: linux, sharepoint, curl

I have a problem while sending file from linux to SharePoint. Everything is fine if I am uploading to existing directory, I use this method:

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file myfile.xls https://sharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.xls
```

Unfortunately problem arises when I point the target to non existing directory, like:

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file myfile.xls https://sharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/nonexist/myfile.xls
```

I would like it to create all necessary directorie on the path. I've tried to use "--create-dirs" CURL option, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to achieve the goal? It doesn't have to be CURL actually, i can use different method available on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name (CLIENT URL) suggests, you will not be able to create new directories on remote SERVERS involving http/https while uploading files.

For downloads involving http/https server, --create-dirs option is applicable only on local machines to create new directories (for instance, when you are downloading a content on to your local linux machine).

However, while using ftp/sftp to a server, you will be able to create new directories on the remote server.