# How can I upload to Confluence using a unix curl command?

Tags: unix, curl, upload, confluence

OK, so I know how to upload to SharePoint thanks to this question:

[How to send file to Sharepoint from Linux creating non existend directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409041/how-to-send-file-to-sharepoint-from-linux-creating-non-existend-directories)

Now I am trying to figure out how to do it with Atlassian's Confluence. Any takers?

What I am looking for is a scriptable Unix command.

Comment: So looking at some Confluence pages, I see *.action pages which usually indicates a Struts implementation. In theory, all I need to do is figure out what action to call with what parameters.

Comment: What about the possibility of using lynx + an expect script to do the upload?

Answer (score 2):

You question needs improving for a real understanding of what you're trying to achieve. That said, you can for example attach a file to a page within Confluence using curl.

The easy way to use do this would be using Bob Swifts [Atlassian/Confluence CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ACLI/Atlassian+Command+Line+Interface) using the `addAttachment` command to add an attachment.

The plugin changed to be commercial a while back, but you can [download the latest free release here](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/16285777/crucible-cli-2.6.0-distribution.zip).

Comment: Agreed. An attachment is acceptable but not optimal. What I was thinking was that I could use web tools to look at the headers and actions processed when a page is edited. See where the text is and then devise a script command that simulates. Unfortunately, I can't do any of this now that my project has tanked and I'm on the lookout for a new gig. :-/  That's the tech industry for ya. Easy come, easy go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running the below command from UNIX.

```
curl -u $USER_NAME:$USER_PASSWORD  -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@${ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME}" -F "comment=File attached via REST API" ${CONFLUENCE_BASE_URL}/rest/api/content/${PAGE_ID}/child/attachment 2>/dev/null
```

More information in this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/using-the-confluence-rest-api-to-upload-an-attachment-to-one-or-more-pages-1014274390.html